# How to capture vuejs errors from a single point inside a component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component where I use lots of axios with `then().catch()` inside the catch I am always throwing `console.error()` like:

```
axios.get(
 //...
).then(
 //...
).catch(
 error => {
  console.error(..)
 }
)
```

and there are other few places I throw errors too. I'm looking if there is a way to globally handle errors. I know maybe for the axios I can user interceptor but does vue components have away to catch errors, so I can unify them inside one function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Vue API provides [the `errorHandler`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorHandler), but it won't catch errors in methods (emphasis mine):

> Assign a handler for uncaught errors during **component render** function and **watchers**.

Examples below.

### Handling of error during component render:

```js
Vue.config.errorHandler = function (err, vm, info)  {
  console.log('[Global Error Handler]: Error in ' + info + ': ' + err);
};

Vue.component('person', {template: '#person-template', props: ['person']});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    people: [
      {name: 'Check the console', address: {zip: 4444}},
      {name: 'No address',     /* address: {zip: 5555} */}
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="person-template">
  <div>
    Name: <b>{{ person.name }}</b> - Zip: {{ person.address.zip }}
  </div>
</template>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="person in people">
    <person :person="person"></person>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Handling of error inside watcher:

```js
Vue.config.errorHandler = function (err, vm, info)  {
  console.log('[Global Error Handler]: Error in ' + info + ': ' + err);
};

Vue.component('person', {template: '#person-template', props: ['person']});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: "Some message"
  },
  watch: {
    message() {
      console.log(this.message.trim());
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  Message: {{ message }}
  <br>
  <button @click="message = null">click here to set message to null and provoke watcher error</button>
</div>
```

## But...

...unfortunately, the `errorHandler` doesn't **work for methods**:

```js
Vue.config.errorHandler = function (err, vm, info)  {
  console.log('[Global Error Handler]: Error in ' + info + ': ' + err);
};

Vue.component('person', {template: '#person-template', props: ['person']});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    goMethod() {
      console.log(this.invalidProperty.trim());
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="goMethod">click to execute goMethod() and provoke error that will NOT be handled by errorHandler</button>
</div>
```

Finally:

> I know maybe for the axios I can user interceptor but does vue components have away to catch errors, so I can unify them inside one function?

Bottom line is there's currently no way to unify them in one function in Vue.

So your guess is right, your best bet is to define [**axios interceptors**](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors):

> ## Axios Interceptors
>
> You can intercept requests or responses before they are handled by
> `then` or `catch`.
>
> ```js
> // Add a request interceptor
> axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
>     // Do something before request is sent
>     return config;
>   }, function (error) {
>     // Do something with request error
>     return Promise.reject(error);
>   });
>
> // Add a response interceptor
> axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
>     // Do something with response data
>     return response;
>   }, function (error) {
>     // Do something with response error
>     return Promise.reject(error);
>   });
> ```

Comment: This should really have had more visibility, it really helped me A LOT thanks! This should be the google result for when you're looking log related searches including Vue, using your suggestion of Vue.config.errorHandler plus [vuejs-logger](https://github.com/justinkames/vuejs-logger), is the solution I needed for completing vuejs-logger combo. Thanks @acdcjunior !
Btw, that was such a nice answer! Ironic how sometimes oneself answers a line and gets more upvotes than with a really well structured one like this.

Comment: "unfortunately, the errorHandler doesn't work for methods" I wonder why this is the case, and why the [docs don't mention it](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorHandler). But, as the comment above noted, this is a great answer, I wish I could upvote it twice

Comment: @Aurelio Yeah, I also wonder. Good thing there's that demo, when they perhaps improve it in future versions we can verify it right away.