# nuxtjs vuejs @error is not firing in a component when trying to load a fallback image

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, onerror

I have a component that I feed with props.

When an image throws a 404 I want to load a fallback image. So far so good.

However the @error function never fires when an image is broken and I can't figure out why! I never get 'hello event' in the console.

The component is on the first level of a nuxt page, my setup is a static SPA.

I tried to implement it as mentioned at the end of this github issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5404

```js
<template>
  <div class="channel">
     <div class="img">
       <img :src="imgUrl" :alt="name" :title="name" @error="getFallBackImage" />
     </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        chanCover: this.cover
      }
    },
    props: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      cover: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    },
    computed: {
      imgUrl() {
        console.log(this.chanCover)
        return "channels/"+this.chanCover+".jpg"
      },
    },
    methods: {
      getFallBackImage(event) {
        console.log("hello event")
        this.chanCover = "default"
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure about the github issue but I've seen [this one before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68027966/8816585), hope it may help. PS: mentioning me like that in the comments doesn't me any kind of notification. [Reach me directly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8816585/kissu?tab=profile) if you want me to be 100% sure of seeing your question.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @kissu that might actually work!

Comment: Keep us updated.

Comment: I am still curious why error is not working here, but I switched everything towards webpack so the proposed solution did work! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: What were you using before?

Comment: I tried using the code above, worked fine on a top level page but not in a component nested in a page ... @error just did not throw even when a url returned a 404.

Comment: About webpack, you were using something else before?

Comment: Ah I see what your asking. I moved my images to be in assets/static folder and if there was an image missing I could catch the 500er error status code which is thrown by webpack/nuxtjs instead of a static/relativ url which throws only a 404 in the console.

Comment: I also tried this one before going to your suggested solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54596396/vue-js-nuxt-js-load-fallback-image-on-404

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/uh2qes45/ the example from the last stack works but does not in my case inside of a component ...

Comment: @kissu this seems to be the problem why my approach does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214634/how-to-capture-vuejs-errors-from-a-single-point-inside-a-component